# How do I create PlosOne Bib references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, abbrvnat.bst

I'm trying to make a [PLOSONE](http://journals.plos.org/plosone) reference and my previous attempt (by citeforme), came for the review. Please help me. 
I'm using `\cite{xx}` so then how should I proceed? How do I make sure that it's correctly formatted? I have no idea what I should do.
Currently, I'm using a `.bst` file with a `.tex` file and I'm trying to compile. I'm editing a `.bib` file in the same folder.

Comment: What is a PLOS one reference?

Comment: Biology open access journal.

Comment: What did the reviewer say? Surely a referee didn't tell you the citations are wrongly formatted?

Comment: He said references looks wrongly formatted. PLOSONE have given the guidelines (showing the correct format) but not shown bib format for each category. What should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: [PLOS One LaTeX instructions](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/latex)

As stated in the PLOS template, your reference information should be included in your .tex file (not submitted separately as .bib or .bbl).  Here is a step-by-step way to include your reference list directly within your .tex file:

1. Compose your LaTeX manuscript as normal, using \cite{bibkey} for reference citations.
2. Compile your manuscript using your .bib file (\bibliography{references}) and the plos2015.bst style file.  This process should output a .bbl file into the same folder as your manuscript.
3. Open the .bbl file and copy/paste its contents into the appropriate position within the manuscript .tex.  Comment out or delete the \bibliography command.
4. Compile your manuscript again. The PDF output should be the same as before.

Comment: `plos2015.bst` is incorrect. PLoS ONE requires comma-separated numerical references in square brackets, but the `.bst` does semicolon-separated in parentheses. After much fiddling around, I found the easiest way to remedy this was to use `\usepackage[square,comma]{natbib}`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Ross's answer may I suggest taking a look at [latex2plos](https://github.com/petarmaric/latex2plos) (shameless plug).

Among other things it will automatically transform a `\bibliography` file inclusion into its equivalent `\begin{thebibliography}...\end{thebibliography}` call, thus embedding the reference information directly into your `.tex` file.

Comment: Please add an description in your own words how your software has to be installed and used to solve the given issue.  And please state if you are the writer of that software! As it stands now this is -- for me, sorry -- more a spam than an valid answer ...

Comment: Fair point, but if you please take a look at latex2plos commit history https://bitbucket.org/petar/latex2plos/commits/ you'll see that it's under active development. I'm currently working on its README and preparing it for publication on the Python Package Index.
In any case, it is usable right now - however I do admit it lacks documentation, which is being worked on.

Comment: As promised, latex2plos 1.0.0 has just been released. Please check if the provided features and documentation are to your liking. If not pull requests are always welcome :)